# Can I export the SNPs between whole genome alignments using the command line?

Tags: sequence-alignment, snp, variation, mauve

I am using [Mauve](http://darlinglab.org/mauve/) to align two whole genomes. I use the following command to get the alignment in xmfa format:

`/Applications/Mauve.app/Contents/MacOS/progressiveMauve ref1.fa ref2.fa --output alignment.xmfa`

I then open the xmfa file in the Mauve GUI and export the SNPs. Is there a way of doing this using a command? I have tried to follow the procedure described [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/mauve/mailman/message/31871278/) but the [link](http://gel.ahabs.wisc.edu/mauve/snapshots) to snapshot releases of Mauve does not work anymore.

I could not find anything in the Mauve command line help:

`/Applications/Mauve.app/Contents/MacOS/progressiveMauve --help`

nor on the [Mauve website](http://darlinglab.org/mauve/).

I tried the procedure described by Konrad Rudolph. I wrote:

MAUVE_DIR=/Applications/Mauve.app/Contents/Java

in the terminal. Is this correct? Don't I need an export and quotation marks to create a bash variable? I tried adding an export and using quotation marks for the file but the error below remained the same.

followed by:

`export CLASSPATH="$(find "$MAUVE_DIR" -name \*.jar -print0 | tr '\0' :)$CLASSPATH"`

followed by:

java org.gel.mauve.analysis.SnpExporter -f alignment.xmfa -o aln.snps

and it seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me with the [download from download page](http://darlinglab.org/mauve/download.html). The download archive contains `Mauve.jar` so the command line in the answer you link to should work.

However, you might need to include all the jar files (not just `Mauve.jar`) in the classpath for this to command work, though. For instance, the following works for me:

```bash
MAUVE_DIR=‹the-dir-containing-Mauve.jar›
export CLASSPATH="$(find "$MAUVE_DIR" -name \*.jar -print0 | tr '\0' :)$CLASSPATH"
java org.gel.mauve.analysis.SnpExporter -f aln.xmfa -o aln.snps
```

… there’s probably a smarter way to make this work but I don’t use Java enough to know how.

Comment: Should I download this file: http://darlinglab.org/mauve/snapshots/2015/2015-02-25/MacOS/Mauve-snapshot_2015-02-25.dmg ? But this is to install mauve, right? Where can I find the Mauve.jar file?

Comment: @charlesdarwin macOS applications are *regular directories*. Open the DMG and go inside the `Mauve.app` dir. Inside that directory you’ll find `/Contents/Java/Mauve.jar`; to display the contents in Finder, use the instructions here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/95942/2392 — but in the terminal you can simply `cd` into the directory.